# Customize Xamarin.Forms.Datepicker to pick and visualize multiple Dates

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, datepicker

i'm kinda new to the whole wpf/xamarin UI thing and want to start my first mobile app.
So, like the title contains already the topic of this question, i would like to use the standard Xamarin.Forms Datepicker to let the user pick multiple Dates.

I guess it will be pretty easy to submit on the Event for picking a date and put this into an array for the selected Dates.

But how can i visualize all the selected Dates in the Datepicker Dialog? Is there any possability to do this with this Control?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you could use Calendar. The SfCalendar plugin provide the `MultiSelection` SelectionMode to do that.

```
 <syncfusion:SfCalendar
            x:Name="calendar"
            SelectionChanged="calendar_SelectionChanged"
            SelectionMode="MultiSelection" />
```

[image]

If you want to get all the list of select dates, you could do that in `calendar_SelectionChanged` event.

```
 private void calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dateAdded = e.DateAdded;
        var dateRemoved = e.DateRemoved;

        if (dateRemoved != null)
        {
            list = dateAdded.Except(dateRemoved).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            list = dateAdded.ToList();
        }         

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i found the syncfusion plugins earlier, but i do need a licencse for them, didn't i ? Thats the reason i would prefer a solution without it :)

Comment: IMHO, this answer should state clearly in the first sentence, that `Calendar` is ***not*** built in to Xamarin; it is a plugin from SyncFusion.

Answer (score 1):

So you want display multiple dates that you previously selected? I dont think that is possible with a Xamarin date picker. The Xamarin date picker only contains one date at a time  [as seen in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker#datepicker-in-an-application). You could make your custom datePicker but you would have to do that for every platform. The way I would do it is update a another display property every time you select a date via a date picker. Something like a clickable label or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

One way to display a variable-length list of editable dates:

- In your "view model" class (or whatever you use as `BindingContext`), maintain the list of dates as a property that is an ObservableCollection: `ObservableCollection<DateTime> Dates { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();`
- In your "view" (or "page") class, have a `ListView` (or the newer `CollectionView`), with an item template that includes a DateView picker. And `Source={Binding Dates}`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker for an example that includes two datepickers. Except instead of explicitly putting two datepickers into your xaml, you'll put the list with its item template.
- Have a button to add a new date to the list.
- In item template, have a button to the right of the datepicker. Use this to remove that date, from the corresponding `Dates` property.

---

If there is a limit to how many dates you want to show, instead of having a ListView, you could manually add the maximum number of date pickers to your View or Page. Similar to the link I gave above. Then add a checkbox next to each; use that to enable/disable that date.